# Bootstrap form styling with ASP.Net single form limitation

Tags: asp.net, webforms, twitter-bootstrap-3

My site uses ASP.Net Web Forms, which limits you to having only one form with `runat="server"`, so I have wrapped all the content in a form tag. Now, I am using Bootstrap 3, and would like to style some of the forms individually with [.form-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). It seems that to use Bootstrap horizontal form styling I would have to either rethink how I use forms on the site, or I would have to use horizontal forms everywhere, neither of which is ideal. So now it looks like I'll have to mimic horizontal forms with custom styling. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think nothing can stop you from replacing `form` tag with `div`. At least official example works fine in JSFiddle.

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

See JSFiddle with [`div`](http://jsfiddle.net/wSJxf/) and with [`form`](http://jsfiddle.net/wSJxf/1/)